# Can anybody help me understand this error message?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am currently working on creating a virtual machine from scratch. I found a video online and I followed it, but when the time has come for me to compile my C++ program(s), the guy said to run the 'make' command to compile it. I used NMake using my Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and it gave me this error message:

```
cl -std=c++11 -c stack-vm.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29112 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
stack-vm.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(285): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(270): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(int)'
stack-vm.cpp(53): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(int)' being compiled
stack-vm.cpp(49): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' being compiled
        cl -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29112 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
main.cpp
        cl -std=c++11 stack-vm.o main.o -o stack-vm
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29112 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'stack-vm.o', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'main.o', object file assumed
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29112.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:stack-vm.exe
/out:stack-vm.exe
stack-vm.o
main.o
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'stack-vm.o'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

NOTE: I have a makefile setup already.

Can anybody help me understand this error? If you need source code, just reach out to me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: The syntax is `/std:c++11`, not `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: `the guy said to run the 'make' command ... I used NMake` They are not the same thing, and this doesn't look like a makefile written to use the VC++ compiler.

Comment: So what can I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: @euneum Either use a toolset directly supported by the project/makefile you have. Or lookup the VC++ [compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options?view=msvc-160) and modify the makefile to use the correct `cl.exe` switches. Or create a standard VC++ project and move the code into it.

Comment: @dxiv so I create a new makefile and cpp file into Visual Studio? That way it will now support it?

Comment: @euneum The standard/native VC++ projects are not makefile based. You go to File / New / Project in VS and start with something simple, like a Win32 console application. Then you can add code and files to that, though you should be prepared for a learning curve if you are not familiar with the environment.

Comment: The MSVC compiler `19.27.29112`, you're using does not support `/std:c++11`: [**Test on coliru**](https://godbolt.org/z/ac5zM1). A colleague told me yesterday that MSVC support for C++11 will come soon. (He found an MS article where they claim they will add this option in the next version.) However, this is not necessarily a show-stopper. Usually, the requirement for C++ standard is "at least". I assume using the default (which might be `/std:c++14`) should be sufficient as well in your case.